# Range and arrays in VBA converting whenever they want. What's going on?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, range

The Range object in VBA is very strange.
Here's my practice code:

```
a = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A3").Columns.Count
b = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A3")
c = b.Columns.Count
```

- a gives me 1, no problem.
- b gives me a 2d array (that's annoyingly indexed starting at 1,1) instead of a Range object
- c naturally, does not work.

How is it possible for a to call the range object and b to be an array? I need a range object to pass into my Functions! 
*I've tried declaring b as a range and range(), this just gives me an error.

Comment: Use option explicit and declare /strongly type all your variables

Comment: `The Range object in VBA is very strange.` - nothing strange. In VBA for assigning object to variable you should always use `Set` : `Set b = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A3")`

Comment: `Option Explicit` is essential

Comment: This is nothing to do with `Option Explicit` (although that's always good advice), and everything to do with using/not using `Set`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to explicitly define your variables if you want the compiler to translate appropriately. Right now it is just guessing at what you are trying to do because you haven't spelled it out.

```
Dim a as Integer
Dim b as Range
Dim c as Integer

a = ...
Set b = ...
c = ...
```

I'm not positive but I think your variables are coming across as Variants which you really want to avoid as this will cause you major headaches down the road.

I would highly recommend setting **Option Explicit** on any code you plan to write going forward so the compiler will complain if you try and reference a variable that has not been explicitly defined. You should be able to set your IDE to default to this on any new module by playing around with the Options menu.

--**Edit**--

Please note that only objects require the Set syntax while primitive datatypes do not. It's a good rule of thumb to explicitly define both in your dimensions though.

Comment: In the example code the OP posted, only `b` should use Set, and not `a` or `c`

Comment: Good Call.. I didn't look closely before but those two variables should be integers and not Ranges... I've edited my answer.

Comment: Yes, thank you! Set was exactly what was missing. I will take your other advice too.